# Why does mysql server packages have perl dependencies in linux distros?

Tags: perl, mysql, rpm, dependencies

I'm trying to clean out some unneeded packages from one of my gentoo boxes with `emerge --depclean`, and I thought I had a few perl modules installed that none of my wanted packages should require.

So, I was a bit surprised to see that:

```
dev-db/mysql-5.5.39 requires >=dev-perl/DBD-mysql-2.9004
```

Shouldn't it be the other way around? Why on earth is `mysql` dependent on a perl package?

The [official MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/source-installation.html) only says that perl is required if running the test scripts when/after compiling from source.

I use the [IUS releases](https://iuscommunity.org/) of the LAMP (where P means PHP) stack on my CentOS boxes, and the `mysql55-server-5.5.39-1.ius.el6.x86_64` package has for instance these requirements (obtained with `rpm -qR`):

```
perl(DBI)  
perl(Data::Dumper)  
perl(File::Basename)  
perl(File::Copy)  
perl(File::Path)  
perl(File::Temp)  
perl(Getopt::Long)  
perl(POSIX)  
perl(Sys::Hostname)  
perl(strict)  
perl(vars)  
perl-DBD-MySQL  
perl-DBI
```

Is there really a need for these requirements on the server packages?

Comment: Well, on gentoo I could actually make it not dependent on DBI (`-perl` USE flag now available), but the question still remains for the binary distros based on RPM and similar technologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the utilities installed as part of the package are `perl` scripts:

```
$ head -n 1 /usr/bin/mysql_fix_extensions
#! /usr/bin/perl

$ head -n 1 /usr/bin/mysql_convert_table_format
#! /usr/bin/perl
```

and so on...

Comment: It would have been nice to put them in a separate package such as `mysql-tools`. I don't have the dependency in gentoo anymore, which is enough for me, though.